# Fading background color of specific item with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have this code where I populate the post coming from my database with a same class. This will produce multiple `<p class="body">{{ $post->body }}</p`

```
@foreach($posts as $post)       
    <article class="post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
        <p class="body">{{ $post->body }}</p>
        <div class="info">
            Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} {{ $post->user->last_name }} on {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
        </div>
    </article>
//Show modal button here
@endforeach
```

And I have a Edit modal where the user can edit the post and save changes. After the button click, I want to change the background color (fading effect) using js or jquery.

This is my code where the specific `<p class="body">{{ $post->body }}</p>` background color change without fading effect.

```
var postBodyElement = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
$('#modal-save').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {body: $('#post-body').val(), postId: postId, _token: token}
})
.done(function (msg) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
    $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
    $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');

    postBodyElement.style.backgroundColor = '#eff0f1';
    setTimeout(function() {
        postBodyElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }, 2000);
});
});
```

[image]
How to add .effect() function to my code or anything? http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) using CSS and only add/remove a class using JavaScript. For example, consider the following snippet. Of course, you can change the timing to your liking. It is also possible to have the background transition in various [different ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) ([more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function)).

```js
$('.post').on('click', function() {
  var $post = $(this);
  $post.addClass('highlight');
  setTimeout(function() { $post.removeClass('highlight'); }, 400);
});
```

```css
.post {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.post.highlight {
  background-color: #ffb457;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">Click me!</div>
<div class="post">Or me!</div>
<div class="post">Or me, maybe...</div>
```

Comment: This will change all the same class in my page.

Comment: No, it will not. I have edited my post to show this.

Comment: Thanks for that. Ill try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This exact functionality (3 second glow to highlight a message) is implemented in the jQuery UI as the highlight effect

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Color and duration are variable.

**Example Code** Toggle a `div` using highlight effect.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>highlight demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
    #toggle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
    <div id="toggle"></div>

    <script>
    $( document ).click(function() {
        $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "highlight" );
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code will change all the same class in my page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I miss this out. I just added this line of code to my current js.

```
$(postBodyElement).effect("highlight", {color: '#eff0f1'}, 5000);
```

So here is my final code:

```
var postBodyElement = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
$('#modal-save').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {body: $('#post-body').val(), postId: postId, _token: token}
})
.done(function (msg) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
    $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
    $(postBodyElement).effect("highlight", {color: '#eff0f1'}, 5000);
    $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
});
});
```